# How do I export BBedit Settings to another mac

Tags: macos, settings

I currently have bbedit setup with my custom shortcuts and I would like to export these setting to my office mac. Is there a way for me to export these settings ?

Answer (score 4):

I was setting up a new machine and found that klanomath's 2016 answer no longer worked for transferring preferences. Here's what worked for me.

As background, the latest versions of BBEdit follow the new macOS guidelines for storing preference information. If you had been updating both your OS and BBEdit on an existing setup, then the preferences continued to be stored in their original locations as described in klanomath's original answer. Now, however, macOS uses the `~/Library/Containers` folder to create a sort of mirror of the main Library structure for individual programs. So if you're trying to transfer preferences, saved clippings, etc., you'll need to look in

`~/Library/Containers/BBEdit/Data/Library/`

Within that folder, you'll find version of the `Preferences`, `BBEdit`, and `Application Support/BBEdit` folders. So if you're transferring from an older BBEdit setup, copy your source

`~/Library/Preferences/com.barebones.bbedit.plist`

to

`~/Library/Containers/BBEdit/Data/Library/Preferences/com.barebones.bbedit.plist`,

on the new machine. Then

`~/Library/BBEdit`

to

`~/Library/Containers/BBEdit/Data/Library/BBEdit`,

and last

`~/Library/Application Support/BBEdit`

to

`~/Library/Containers/BBEdit/Data/Library/Application Support/BBEdit`

If your source preferences are already in `~/Library/Containers/BBEdit/Data/Library/`, then just do a straight copy from old to new for the folders and files listed.

You might also want/need to follow steveb's advice about renaming the Sleep State file. I did that to be safe.

Comment: +1. 
For all who are interested: more such technical info can be found in the official "BBEdit User Manual". It is bundled along with BBEdit application (top menu "Help > User Manual") and is also available online: https://www.barebones.com/support/bbedit/manual.html

Comment: @informatik01 where in the manual is information regarding acullum's answer? thanks!

Comment: @aequalsb In the official BBEdit [User manual](https://s3.amazonaws.com/BBSW-download/BBEdit_15.0_User_Manual.pdf) (version 15 at the time of writing this), chapter 2, section **"Preference Files and Folders"**  (page 41 in the above posted manual).

Comment: @informatik01 THANKS! the Terminal export plist command explained there looks very promising! but i can't confirm... i just ran out of time for now to continue setting up a new Mac... and i wanted to thank you for the prompt and helpful reply!

Comment: this also should explain why copying the plist file just doesn't really work... it certainly has not ever worked in the past and now for me in regards to the GUI... copying Clippings has worked but that's not surprising considering they are just flat files

Comment: @aequalsb You're welcome! I mainly rely on the much more powerful and flexible Visual Studio Code, which in addition has a nice "_Sync Settings_" feature out of the box. And I use BBEdit for really simple stuff, like editing ZSH configs etc. One feature that BBedit has unlike VS Code is it can show the content of [**Plist**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) files without extra plugins.

Comment: i'm a 20+ year user of BBEdit... i guess i should consider Visual Studio before it's too late lol

Answer (score 1):

To export your settings and preferences to a new Mac copy the following files and folders to it:

file:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.barebones.bbedit.plist
```

folders:

```
~/Library/BBEdit
~/Library/Application Support/BBEdit
```

`~` indicates your user folder.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me; possibly because I am using a different version of BBEdit. The additional task I had to do is update the file name for `~//Library/BBEdit/Sleep State-<some_id>.appstate` (where "<some_id>" appears to be unique to a machine).  I did this by first running BBEdit on the target machine to determine the new "<some_id>" then I performed the tasks in this answer from @klanomath.  After that I renamed `~//Library/BBEdit/Sleep State-<some_id>.appstate` to `~//Library/BBEdit/Sleep State-<new_some_id>.appstate`.

Comment: These tasks should also be performed w/o BBEdit running.

Answer (score 0):

I had to open the program on the old and new computers, open preferences and duplicate settings from one to the other. Nothing else worked for me.